# Concatenate name fields in an Access query using IIF() without printing spaces?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, concatenation, iif

First of all, I am a newbie.  Please keep that in mind...

That said, I have used a simple formula to concatenate name fields in a student database in Access using a query (I am using Access 2013 but must maintain compatibility with Access 2010).  It reads as such:

`Student Name: IIf(IsNull([Preferred First Name]),[First Name],[Preferred First Name]) & " " & [Last Name]`

Which shows the student's preferred first name and last name, or first name and last name.  If it turns out first (preferred or given) is null and/or last is null, obviously it prints null where appropriate.

[Example of formula output using fictional names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI5Fp.png)

Well, that is where the issue comes in.  As you can see in the example, one student only has first name Christine, which prints as `"Christine "`.  Another only has last name Alexander, which prints as `" Alexander"`.  It is printing the space no matter what.

Now I now it is possible using `Iif` to get around this -- it's used in a sample database like so:

`Student Name: IIf(IsNull([Last Name]),IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[First Name]),IIf(IsNull([First Name]),[Last Name],[First Name] & " " & [Last Name]))`

I want to incorporate the "Preferred First Name" field into that formula, but I just can't wrap my head around it.  It seems to work backwards from how I would say this in natural speech, and it seems to be missing values.  In plain English I envision it like this:

*If [Last Name] is null, print only [Preferred First Name], unless that is null, in which case print only [First Name], unless that is also null, in which case print null.

Otherwise if [Last Name] has a value, print [Preferred First Name] & " " & [Last Name], unless [Preferred First Name] is null, in which case print [First Name] & " " & [Last Name], unless [First Name] is also null, in which case just print [Last Name].*

(To clarify, there are sometimes cases where we are unable to get a student's full name, so I can't simply make all fields required, which is why I want to make sure it prints correctly regardless of what data is available.)

I apologize if this is too simple a question for this site, but it seemed like the best place to ask.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [Trim](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/trim.php) function.  So, your string would look like:

```
Student Name: Trim(IIf(IsNull([Preferred First Name]),Trim([First Name]),
Trim([Preferred First Name])) & " " & Trim([Last Name]))
```

Trim each individual field (just in case the data got entered with an extra space or 2, which happens occasionally), and then trim the entire resultant string to get rid of any spaces as well.

Comment: I would not have even thought to use Trim -- this is so much simpler, and looks to be working just as I had expected -- thank you for the help!